# Java RegEx Pattern not matching (works in .NET)

Tags: java, regex

Below is an example that is producing an exception in Java (and not matching the input). Perhaps I misunderstood the JavaDoc, but it looks like it should work. Using the same pattern and input in C# will produce a match.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pattern = "aspx\\?uid=([^']*)";      
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = p.matcher("id='page.aspx?uid=123'");
        System.out.println(m.groupCount() > 0 ? m.group(1) : "No Matches");     
    }
}
```

EDIT: I should note the JavaDoc says the following about Matcher.groupCount

> Any non-negative integer smaller than
>   or equal to the value returned by this
>   method is guaranteed to be a valid
>   group index for this matcher.

Comment: m.matches() == false even though m.groupCount() = 1

Comment: I guess the JavaDoc should mention that the value returned from Matcher.groupCount is only valid if Matcher.find() returns true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling

```
m.find();
```

after the `.matcher` statement.

Comment: Well, that explains it. The example actually left out the find, but going back and looking at the original code that raised the issue for me, find() was only called during a specific condition. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's throwing an exception because the pattern didn't match but you tried to get a group from it (`m.matches()` would be false here); `groupCount()` will return the number of groups that would be in a match, regardless of if there actually was one. As for why the match isn't working, Java Patterns match on the entire string, not on a substring

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the flaw in the code that is causing the exception. However, I am still not clear on your last statement. The pattern SHOULD produce a match. It does not. I know that there is a reason, and I was hoping I could get an explaination, as well as possibly a fix for my expression. Appreciated.

Comment: It's what I said; Patterns match on the whole string. Thus the pattern "a" will not match the string "ba", but the pattern ".a" will. You can use `Matcher.find()` to get around that, as [KennyTM said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724222/java-regex-pattern-not-matching-works-in-net/2724274#2724274)

Comment: I did up-vote your response because you were correct in that I had a flaw in my code.